# How to persist Serilog.Sinks.Xamarin logs

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, serilog

Sinks.Xamarin on a xamarin forms app, so far it works great, but I'm looking forward to persist the logs so I can send them to the server later.
this are the solutions I have found so far

1) sqlite
[Serilog.Sinks.SQLite only write once in db in Xamarin Form(Android)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51748532/serilog-sinks-sqlite-only-write-once-in-db-in-xamarin-formandroid)

2)Json file
Serilog.Extensions.Logging.File

so far I like more the second option but that nuget is for asp.net mvc, is there any option for xamarin forms that persist the log in a file?

Answer (score 1):

This looks like a case of **data persistence**.

Data can be persisted using `Application.Current.Properties`.

> The Properties dictionary uses a string key and stores an object value.

For instance, you could put the following line in `OnDisappearing()` in your cs.

```
Application.Current.Properties ["store"] = someClass.ID;
```

In the `OnStart()` or `OnResume()` methods:

```
if (Application.Current.Properties.ContainsKey("id"))
{
    var id = Application.Current.Properties ["id"] as int;
    // do something with id
}
```

[Here's](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/application-class#Properties_Dictionary) some more helpful documentation of this.